# After Login with Facebook Android -Other Activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

When i implement Facebook in my app , i need send the profile image to other activity , but when i start the other Activity, the image is null.
When i see the logs , the other activity starts first and the load of the image starts before, for this reason the image in other activity is null....This is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private UserPojo userLogin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

    userLogin=new UserPojo();
    loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {

                Log.d("MainActivity", "Put the name");

            } else {
                username.setText("You are not logged in.");
            }
        }
    });
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            facebookLogin(session);
            **getPicture();**
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");

            Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("usuario", userLogin);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
        }
    }
};


public void **getPicture**(){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams rp=new RequestParams();
        rp.add("type", "large");
    client.get("http://graph.facebook.com/407367422756988/picture", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPostProcessResponse(
                ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostProcessResponse(instance, response);


        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg2 , 0, arg2.length);
            if(bitmap==null)
                Log.e("Bit","Null");
            else
                Log.e("Bit","Not Null");
            userLogin.setImage(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Fallo","Fallo");

        }
    });
}
public void facebookLogin(final Session session) {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    Log.e("Token",session.getAccessToken());
    rp.put("token", session.getAccessToken());
    client.post("http://192.168.1.72:8000/api-token/login/facebook/", rp,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                        Throwable arg3) {

                    userLogin.setUsername("eRICK");


                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("Action", "Manadando");
                    Log.e("Action",new String(arg2));
                }

            });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    uiHelper.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("TAG","Final de la actividad");


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}
```

The metodh getPicture() , extract de profile picture .... I need help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your statusCallback, you called the following asynchronous/non-blocking method:

```
facebookLogin(session);
getPicture();
```

Before these two methods get their results and call

```
userLogin.setUsername("eRICK"); //and
userLogin.setImage(bitmap);
```

You call:

```
startActivity(i);
```

That is why the image is null.

A quick fix, but not the best fix is as follow:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getPicture();
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (userLogin.getUserName==null) {
                facebookLogin(session); 
                return;
            }

            if (userLogin.getImage()==null) {
                // Image not ready yet
                return;
            }

            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
                Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("usuario", userLogin);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I can't figure out how to get a session outside the call() method. If you know how to get it, you should also put your facebookLogin() method in onCreate() method.

Comment: What do you think is the best fix? , Because you say "A quick fix, but not the best fix is as follow:"

Comment: In my answer, I'm just trying to avoid you from getting race condition. It depends. Let say you want to start the activity after a facebook session is opened, you should put you startActivity() in facebookLogin() onSuccess() method.